# how can i get project_id by remarks in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have manager remark model that takes input as a remark and decision value and saves it with the project site ID. I have a project site model that takes input as name, date, and file and stores it. Many remarks have a many to one relation with project site ID, and the project site belongs to the manager remark. I want to access the decision attribute boolean value in project site index form, but I am unable to access that boolean value in the index page of the project site. Here is my code of project site and manager remarks model, view and controller-

project site index.html.erb

```
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Attendance</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @project_sites.each do |project_site| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= project_site.name.titleize %></td>
          <td><%= project_site.date %></td>
          <td><%= link_to ' View attendance', project_site.file, :class => "fi-page-export-csv" %></td>
          <td><%= "here i want to access manager remark decision value" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Remark ', project_site %><span>(<%= project_site.manager_remarks.size %>)</span></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_site_path(project_site) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project_site, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

project site controller

```
    def index
    @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @manager_remark = ManagerRemark.joins(:project_site).where(:project_sites => { :user_id => @user.id })
  end

  # GET /project_sites/1
  # GET /project_sites/1.json
  def show
    @manager_remark = ManagerRemark.new
    @manager_remark.project_site_id = @project_site.id

  end

  # GET /project_sites/new
  def new
    @project_site = ProjectSite.new
  end
  def project_site_params
      params.require(:project_site).permit(:name, :date, :file)
    end
```

manager_remark controller

```
    class ManagerRemarksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @manager_remark = ManagerRemark.new(remark_params)
    @manager_remark.project_site_id = params[:project_site_id]
    @manager_remark.save

    redirect_to project_site_path(@manager_remark.project_site)
  end

  def remark_params
    params.require(:manager_remark).permit(:remark, :decision)
  end

end
```

manager_remark view form

```
<%= form_for [ @project_site, @manager_remark ] do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <%= f.radio_button :decision, true  %>
      <%= f.label :approve %>
      <%= f.radio_button :decision, false  %>
      <%= f.label :reject %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="medium-6 cloumns">
      <%= f.label :remark %><br/>
      <%= f.text_area :remark %>
    </div>

      </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :project_sites do
    resources :manager_remarks

  end

  get '/project_manager_level_two' => 'project_manager_level_two#index'
  get '/project_managers' => 'project_managers#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Can you show your associations? A project-site belongs-to manager-remark? Only one? From your initial line it is the other way round? A manager-remark belongs_to project? And please clearly specify the intention: should there be only one manager-remark for a project-site? (because I would assume there could be mulitple remarks --and thus multiple decisions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `ProjectSite` that contains a `ManagerRemark` with a decision, right? If that's the case, the simple answer is:

```
<%= project_site.ManagerRemark.decision %>
```

If you are saying that each `ProjectSite` has many `ManagerRemark`s, you'll want to place the above inside a loop, like so:

```
<% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
<%= manager_remark.decision %><br/>
<% end %>
```

This assumes that your models are correctly configured to recognize these relationships. The above may also be optimized by adding an `include` clause to your fetch inside the controller and there's no need to fetch the ManagerRemark objects separately. Therefore, you'd probably want something like:

```
def index
    @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.includes( :manager_remark ).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem or is there more that I missed? Is this the correct answer for your situation? If so, you probably want to mark it as such so that others can easily find it.